Solve the equation: $(x+2)(x+3)(x-4)(x-5)=60$
The problem
Solve the equation: $(x+2)(x+3)(x-4)(x-5)=60$
My idea
I thought of multiplying $(x+2)(x-4)$ and $(x+3)(x-5)$ and got that $(x^2-2x-15)(x^2-2x-8) =60$. I noted $x^2-2x-15=z$ and got that $z(z+7)=60=z^2+7z\implies z^2+2\times \frac{7}{2}\times z+\frac{49}{4}=\frac{289}{4}=(z+\frac{7}{2})^2$ and from here we get 2 cases.

if $z+\frac{7}{2}= \frac{17}{2} \implies z=5=x^2-2x-15\implies x^2-2x+1=21\implies (x -1)^2=21\implies x=\sqrt{21}+1, 1-\sqrt{21}$

2)if $z+ \frac{7}{2}= \frac{-17}{2}\implies z=-12=x^2-2x-15 \implies x^2-2x+1=4\implies x=3,-1$
I am not sure if my idea is right because I took a lot of cases and some of the answers include $\sqrt{21}$

That is fine. It's how I would have approached it.

Your way is fine, as an alternative we have that
$$(x+2)(x+3)(x-4)(x-5)=60 \iff (x^2-2x)^2-23(x^2-2x)+60=0$$
then by $t=x^2-2x$, we need to solve
$$t^2-23t+60=0$$
giving $t=3, t =20$ then

$x^2-2x-3=0 \implies x=-1, x=3$
$x^2-2x-20=0\implies x=1+\sqrt{21},x=1-\sqrt{21}$


Can you demystify the first step? (Should it be $-60$ at the end?)

@CalvinLin I've checked it right now, it should be fine. I check again. Thanks

@CalvinLin I've completed the calculation and it seems fine! let me know if you can see something wrong. Thanks

We have,
$$\color{red}{(x+2)}\color{blue}{(x+3)}\color{red}{(x-4)}\color{blue}{(x-5)}=60$$
Note that $-1$ is the midpoint of $2$ and $-4$. It is also the midpoint of $3$ and $-5$. Let $t=x-1$, the equation will be:
$$(t+3)(t+4)(t-3)(t-4)=60$$
$$(t^2-9)(t^2-16)=60$$
Now it is easy to solve for $t^2$ and $x$.

This is by far the best solution of the ones available.

Was this solution invisible while I was editing the mine? I can see this one only now

Start by expanding $(x+2)(x+3)(x-4)(x-5)$. This will leave you with $$x^4-4x^3-19x^2+46x+120=60$$ Now we want to move the $60$ to the other side:
$$x^4-4x^3-19x^2+46x+60=0$$
Now that we've solved for $0$ we can easily factor. We can use the rational root theorem to factor it:
$$(x+1)(x-3)(x^2-2x-20)=0$$
We can easily solve the $(x+1)$ and the $(x-3)$ giving us the solutions $x=-1$ and $x=3$. We need to solve the $x^2-2x-20$ term which we must use the quadratic formula for. This will yield $1\pm \sqrt{21}$.
So after all of this we find the solutions are: $x=-1,x=3,x=1+\sqrt{21},x=1-\sqrt{21}$

You can substitute the values of $x$ you found to check whether the solutions are correct.
For example for $x=3$,
$$
(3+2)(3+3)(3-4)(3-5) = (5)(6)(-1)(-2) = 60
$$
For $x=-1$
$$
(-1+2)(-1+3)(-1-4)(-1-5) = (1)(2)(-5)(-6) = 60
$$
For $x=1+\sqrt{21}$
$$
(1+\sqrt{21}+2)(1+\sqrt{21}+3)(1+\sqrt{21}-4)(1+\sqrt{21}-5) = 12(5) = 60
$$
since
$$
(1+\sqrt{21}+2)(1+\sqrt{21}-4)=(3+\sqrt{21})(-3+\sqrt{21})=12
$$
and
$$
(1+\sqrt{21}+3)(1+\sqrt{21}-5)=(4+\sqrt{21})(-4+\sqrt{21})=5
$$
You can check for  $x=1-\sqrt{21}$

Yes, you can solve in this way:
$$0 = z^2 + 7z - 60 = (z + 12)(z - 5) \implies z = -12, 5$$
So now you can go back to find e.g.:
$$x^2 - 2x - 15 = -12 \iff x^2 - 2x - 3 = 0 \iff (x-3)(x+1) = 0 \implies x = 3, -1$$
In retrospect, you may have just tried these small values. In other words, plugging in a few integers to get an idea of your expression's values could have shown that both $x=-1$ and $x=3$ yield solutions.
You can proceed by now continuing with the other value of $z$ and solving the corresponding quadratic:
$$x^2 - 2x - 15 = 5 \iff x^2 - 2x - 20 = 0 \implies x = \frac{2\pm\sqrt{84}}{2} = 1 \pm \sqrt{21}$$
An alternate approach might include e.g. spotting the integer solutions above initially, and then using something like synthetic division (or factoring) to reduce the initial quartic to a quadratic.
In any event, the $\sqrt{21}$ is no issue, and you can check on e.g. Desmos or WolframAlpha that these are, in fact, the correct solutions.

Given,
$$(x+2)(x+3)(x-4)(x-5)=60$$
Whenever there is an equation of form
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)=C$$
Where sum of one pair of constants is equal to the sum of the other pair of constants,
Take some parametric term, $$t=x+\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$$
$\therefore$ In the given equation $t=x+\frac{2+3-4-5}{4}\implies t=x-1$
$\Rightarrow x=t+1$
Substituting this in the given equation we get
$$(t+3)(t+4)(t-3)(t-4)$$
$$(t^{2}-9)(t^{2}-16)=60$$
Now consider $k=t^2$ and solve for k and backtrack to $x$.
